# bootstrap grid full width top 3 columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I can't get the top 3 columns to occupy 100% of the width, as you can see in the example there are margins to the right and to the left.

I need the 3 columns above to occupy the same width as the table below, I'm just starting with bootstrap and I don't see how to solve it.

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, but I can't quite see it.

Thanks and best regards

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <title>Example</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row general pt-3 pb-3">
      <div class="col-md-12 pb-1">
        <div class="row row-centered d-print-none" id="filters">
          <div class="col-md-4 col-centered bg-transparent text-dark text-center">
            <div class="p-2 bg-dark text-white">
              <h6>FILTER 1</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-centered bg-transparent text-dark text-center">
            <div class="p-2 bg-dark text-white">
              <h6>FILTER 2</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-centered bg-transparent text-dark text-center">
            <div class="p-2 bg-dark text-white">
              <h6>FILTER 3</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row row-centered">
          <div class="col-md-12 col-centered pt-2 mb-2 bg-dark text-white">
            <h5 class="text-center">TABLE CAPTION</h5>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row row-centered">
          <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-sm">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>C1</th>
                <th>C2</th>
                <th>C3</th>
                <th>C4</th>
                <th>C5</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            </tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>AA</td>
              <td>BB</td>
              <td>CC</td>
              <td>DD</td>
              <td>EE</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you must include your `scripts` and `links` into your `head`.
Then you have an orphan closing tag : `</script>` which could lead to issues.

Then, take a look at your `col-md-4` for each of your filters. They add 15px padding. Remove the `padding-left` of your first col-md-4 element, and remove the `padding-right` of your last col-md-4 element.
*Remove stands for set to **0px**.*

Comment: changed but same problem.

Comment: Please let me know if setting padding to 0px on col-md-4 solves your problem.